# Trying to use jQuery to check for a validate email address in Gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I did not see any example from the list displayed here that meets our requirement.

We are trying to validate a couple of GridView form controls.

One of those is email control.

The requirements are:

First, ensure that an email is entered. This works.
The second requirement is more challenging. This second part is to ensure that user entered a valid email address.

I have tried several possibilities but none has worked out so far.

Any ideas how to check for a valid email address in GridView using jQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=GridView1] [id*=btnAdd]").click(function () {
            //Find the GridView Row using the LinkButton reference.
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            //Find the request type TextBox control.
            var txtrequestType = row.find("[id*=txtrequestType]");
            var txtemailAdd = row.find("[id*=txtemailAdd]");

            //Find the DropDownList control.
            //  var ddlCountries = row.find("[id*=ddlCountries]");
            var message = "";
            //Validate the request type TextBox control.
            if ($.trim(txtrequestType.val()) == "") {
                message += "Please enter a new request type.\n";
            }
            //Validate the email TextBox control.
            if ($.trim(txtemailAdd.val()) == "") {
                message += "Please enter a new email address.\n";
            }
           // This validation is not working
            if (!(txtemailAdd.indexOf('@') == -1)) {
                message += "Please enter a valid email address.\n";
            }
            //Validate the DropDownList control.
            //   if (ddlCountries.val() == "") {
            //     message += "Please select Country.";
            // }
            //Display error message.
            if (message != "") {
                alert(message);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your conditional logic is backwards and returns true if  `@` exists ... get rid of `!`

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks so much. That was a new solution I attempted before posting here but forgot to make that correction. It is working now and below is the script that worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($.trim(txtemailAdd.val()).indexOf('@') == -1)) {
    message += "Please enter a valid email address.\n";
}
```